# c# get objects properties values into string array

Tags: c#

I have a simple class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
}
```

Let's say that I have a collection of `Items`:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { A = 1, B = 2},
    new Item { A = 3, B = 4}
};
```

What I need is a LINQ query to cast each `Item` object values into string array, so that for example above I will get:

```
IEnumerable<string []> result = { 
  {"1", "2"}, // First Item
  {"3", "4"} // Second Item
}
```

Any ideas how to acomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items.Select(item => new [] { item.A.ToString(), item.B.ToString() }).ToList()
```

Comment: The `.ToList` is redundant, `.Select` already returns an `IEnumerable` (as per the OP's requirement). I was about to hit submit on the same answer when you beat me by a second or two.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C#7 you can utilize ValueTuple's instead of an array containing two elements like this:

```
var result = items.Select(x => (A: x.A.ToString(), B: x.B.ToString()));
```